# Which template is used in this article?

Tags: templates, document-classes, article

I'm looking for a document class or a template that can reproduce the appearance of [this JASA article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221849529_On_the_role_of_glottis-interior_sources_in_the_production_of_voiced_sound/link/5416feb70cf2fa878ad43d19/download) as close as possible, especially the nice fonts for text and math. A screenshot of the article is shown below.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

[image: PNG screenshot of JASA 2011 article[1]]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... It is difficult to say, hence it seems to be a customized layout...

Comment: Thanks! Do you perhaps know the text and math font? I've seen them in several other articles and books.

Comment: It seems as Times and Helvetica or Optima

Comment: Should use both text and the math font in the same font except the Greek, hence Greek symbols will pickup by some standard mathfont families, like `mathptmx` and `newtxmath` etc...

Comment: Thank you very much. How would I select these fonts with a pdfLatex compiler, for example in [this Overleaf project](https://www.overleaf.com/project/5d303b149eea1245dde5d91c)?

Comment: Oops...sorry, I didn't use `overleaf` till date.. Better to go with `\usepackage{newtxtext}\usepackage{newtxmath}` hope it may works, hence these are free fonts with all LaTeX distributions...

Comment: That worked. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear...cheers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the intstruction to authors:

> Authors who wish to use LaTeX
>   should use the JASA LaTeX package, which is
>   available here: http://acousticalsociety.org/preparinglatex-manuscripts/

But the link really is:

https://acousticalsociety.org/preparing-latex-manuscripts/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found that link also, but unfortunately JASA has changed their format to a new (personally: inferior) style. The JASA articles around 2011 all have the template mentioned in the question.

Comment: @marnix Then, see the fonts in the PDF properties:  there are  about two dozens of fonts  (SourceSansProRegular, Martel-Regular, ...). Reproduce that style from the scratch will take time even if you have that fonts.

Comment: OK will do. Thanks